# Data Transformation: Best Practices and Design Patterns

Tags: design-patterns, data-transfer

This is a rather theoretical question. I am building an MVC data-driven application. My question is about transforming data from database fields into displayable data. For example, I would like to transform a Boolean 1 or 0 int a string "Yes" or "No". I would like to tansform a firstName field and a lastName field into a "FullName field. (ie: "John" and "Smith" becomes "Smith, John"). and I would like to transform fields containing user_id's into hyperlinks to detail pages. (ie, a user_id of 17 is tranformed into a link containing: userdetails.php?id=17)

I know that I could do this in the SQL query. (SELECT CONCAT(lastName .", " .firstName) AS fullName). I know that I could write an object for every type of list that I need, and manually do the transformations in said object. I know that I could even do some of this with helpers at the View level.

But what I am thinking of is something kind of like a "Data Transform Object". It would take an array of records in the constructor. It would then have a "transformation object" assigned to each field that would transform data. It would then have a method to get the transformed data as an array.

Why do all of this? Well, one reason is because it seems to be cool object-oriented design. Another reason is so that we have the data in it's pure form that we can work with, but we can easily transform it into a display-ready format.

Psudocode follows:

```
class yesNoTransform extends dataTransform {

    public function ($field) {
        if($field == true) {
            return "TRUE";
        } else {
            return "FALSE"
        }
    }

    public function transform (
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). It matches your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Will suggest you to use Java EE **DAO pattern**.

Through this, you can abstract all Database related stuff. Make sure that you handle all DB exception in DAO and then transform response to Value Object or DTO. So your DAO will return DTO object to the calling method or Controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid code bloating, prefer that, this would mean prefer doing these small post-processig transformations right at SQL. Do more with less, less code to maintain, less bugs. If you absolutely must do the transformation in code, then I would actually recommend a "Filter"-based approach. You have filters that comply to a common abstraction and they process result sets saved in e.g. `List` of `Map` instances. You create a chain of filters, where each filter delegates to the next for processing and each applies a specific transformation to the result set. That's the [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Where did you see Java in the question?

Comment: OK fixed it, my answer is quite Language independent